# Rails active_storage with rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, rails-activestorage

I'm using rails 5.2 api and active_storage

I know when you are using full fat rails in your views you can do stuff like

`image.file.upload.variant(resize: "100x100")`

But since im using the api version, how can I get the url for this? does anyone know of documentation that covers using active storage in an api?

FYI, I already tried `url_for(image.file.upload.variant(resize: "100x100"))` it doesn't work.

At this point, Im kinda tempted to go back to paperclip.

Comment: why it doesn't work, what are you getting when you use url_for(variant)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure since I haven't use ActiveStorage much yet, but try this `.processed.service_url` from the docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html

For what I understand, the first time you call that it creates the variant and uploads it, then it stays there and the next time it just gets the url.